# Проблема с вывод значений в Flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Всем привет, я делаю проект, используя Flask и все прочие к нему модули. При использовании Flask-Admin, когда я создаю новую запись в БД, вместо имени пользователя и названия урока, стоит их id.(представлено на рисунке 1)
Рисунок 1[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли что то сделать, чтобы появилось имя пользователя и название урока, а не их Id?
Ниже, предcтавлен код, где создается БД и таблицы

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager
 
login = LoginManager()
db = SQLAlchemy()
 
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
 
    def set_password(self,password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
     
    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)

class Lessons(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'lessons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nameLessons = db.Column(db.String(50))

class Statement(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'statement'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fio_name = db.Column(db.String(70), db.ForeignKey('users.name'), nullable=False)
    fio = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('fio', lazy='dynamic'))
    lesson_name = db.Column(db.String(70), db.ForeignKey('lessons.nameLessons'), nullable=False)
    lesson_title = db.relationship('Lessons', backref=db.backref('lessons', lazy='dynamic'))
    grades = db.Column(db.String(1))
 
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ:
надо было просто добавить

```
    __tablename__ = "lessons"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nameLessons = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return  (self.nameLessons)

class Statement(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "statement"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fio_name = db.Column(db.String(70), db.ForeignKey("users.name"), nullable=False)
    fio = db.relationship("User", backref="fio")
    lesson_name = db.Column(db.String(70), db.ForeignKey("lessons.nameLessons"), nullable=False)
    lesson_title = db.relationship("Lessons", backref=db.backref("lessons", lazy="dynamic"))
    grades = db.Column(db.String(1))    

    def __repr__(self):
        return  (self.fio_name)д`
```